# Angular empty input validation fails with currency

Tags: html, angular

Consider an HTML input form with red error text that informs when field is empty.  Notice it relies on `ng-show=$error.required && $touched`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="qp-cargo-value" name="qpCargo" placeholder="$" type="text" 
               class="form-group" currency="229" data-ng-model="cargoValue" required>
    </div>
    <div class="rederrorlabel"
         ng-show="myform.qpCargo.$error.required && myform.qpCargo.$touched">
        Error - Cargo value is required
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine for fields without the `ccy` attribute.  But for inputs with `ccy`, when the input is empty the default value stored in angular is not `null` but `$`, which fails to trip the `$error.required` condition
[image]

Here is console output for the value as I enter and then delete values, confirming that it never gets set to null but rather to `"$"`.

[image]

Is there anyway to retain the `ccy` formatting but somehow still use `$error.requried` in an input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the standard seems to be to have an input prepend for $ and only take in the amount not the symbol.

Bootstrap EX:

[image: Bootstrap currency input]

If you prefer to leave it the way it is, you can write a method that checks for a valid entry returning a bool and use it for the ng-show.

```js
  public currencyValidation(): boolean {
    return myform.qpcargo.value.replace('$', "").length < 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="qp-cargo-value" name="qpCargo" placeholder="$" type="text" 
               class="form-group" currency="229" data-ng-model="cargoValue" required>
    </div>
    <div class="rederrorlabel"
         ng-show="currencyValidation() && myform.qpCargo.$touched">
        Error - Cargo value is required
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats a good idea, thanks.  Really it's not the dollar symbol that is important when using `ccy` but that it adds commas.  So entering `99999` autoformats to `$99,999` and users avoid dumb, costly mistakes.  I will try the custom validation, thank you